# Is it possible to assign integers to words in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, int, nlp

I want to take an array of words then convert into a bunch of integers so that some unique integer `k` corresponds to some unique word `j`.

Example:

Sentence: `"The cat sat on the mat"`
Number format: `1 2 3 4 1 5`

Is this possible in Python and if so how do I do it?

Comment: Yes; find a tutorial and read about dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a counter and a dictionary:

```
index = 1
word_to_index = {}
for word in sentence.split():
    if word in word_to_index:
        # already seen
        continue
    word_to_index[word.lower()] = index
    index += 1
```

This assigns a unique index to each (lowercased) word; now you can use those to output your numbers:

```
print sentence
for word in sentence.split():
    print word_to_index[word.lower()],
```

If you want to use some more Python standard library magic, use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) combined with [`itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

word_to_index = defaultdict(count(1).next)

print sentence
for word in sentence.split():
    print word_to_index[word.lower()],
```

For Python 3, you'd have to use `count(1).__next__`, as well as the more obvious switch to using `print()` as a function (`print(word_to_index[word.lower()], end=' ')`).

This will *autogenerate* indices for each word. Demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import count
>>> sentence = "The cat sat on the mat"
>>> word_to_index = defaultdict(count(1).next)
>>> print sentence
The cat sat on the mat
>>> for word in sentence.split():
...     print word_to_index[word.lower()],
... 
1 2 3 4 1 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
import itertools

c = itertools.count()
answer = collections.defaultdict(c.__next__)
for word in sentence.lower().split():
    answer[word]
```

Output:

```
In [29]: answer
Out[29]: defaultdict(<method-wrapper '__next__' of itertools.count object at 0x10a420c08>, {'mat': 4, 'sat': 2, 'the': 0, 'on': 3, 'cat': 1})
```

To print out the indices:

```
for word in sentence.lower().split():
    print(answer[word], end=' ')
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 0 4
```

Of course, you could make the indices start at `1` by changing the default argument to `itertools.count`: `itertools.count(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a list of the unique words in the sentence, then going through the sentence word by word and looking up each word's position in that list.

```
sentence = "The cat sat on the mat"
words_in_sentence = sentence.lower().split()
unique_words = list(set(words_in_sentence))
print [unique_words.index(word) for word in words_in_sentence]
```